# Android Linux Kernel Details

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source

I wanted to know if the android uses 32 bit Linux kernel or 64 bit one or it has support for both?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK:

- There is no 32/64 bit Linux kernel. You can build same kernel for 32 or 64 bit CPUs.
- Android most of us know runs on ARM CPUs, and those are 32 bit

Comment: Thank you. But ARM is also coming up with 64 bit Architecture (http://www.eetimes.com/electronics-news/4230160/ARM-unveils-64-bit-architecture) but i don't know if it will be used by android.

Comment: In that case, WOW. Should keep up my skills on Android.

Comment: user1278035: I'm not sure there are any ARMv8 (64 bit) chips already available, but I have no doubts these will be supported in some future version of Android.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for android to use a 64 bit kernel. Its meant to work on a small device for small applications, not support large memory or huge server based configurations.

I wonder why you would have this question ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted port some c++ libs into android for which i wanted to know if android kernel is 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score -1):

[http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/News/How-Much-Linux-Is-in-Android] Here they mentioned android uses linux version 2.6.32 so it is a 32 bit.

Comment: sorry i didn't mean that it is 2.6.32 so it is 32 bit ... what i mean that i guess 2.6 is 32 bit os ...

Comment: Ohh downvoted :) Linux has had a 64 bit version since 2001 at 2.4 :) However 99% of the ARM processors are 32 bit, so Android is 32 bit.